# Dynamic linq lambda expression to select specific columns

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

Trying to select few of the columns from the given list of type T.

Got following code:

```
        var myList = new List<Class>(){ //data};

        // new statement "new Data()"
        var xNew = Expression.New(typeof(Class));

        // create initializers
        var bindings =
            d.Select(o =>
            {

                // property "Field1"
                var mi = typeof(Class).GetProperty(o.Name);

                // original value "o.Field1"
                var xOriginal = Expression.Property(parameter, mi);

                // set value "Field1 = o.Field1"
                return Expression.Bind(mi, xOriginal);
            }
        );

        // initialization "new Data { Field1 = o.Field1, Field2 = o.Field2 }"
        var xInit = Expression.MemberInit(xNew, bindings);

        // expression "o => new Data { Field1 = o.Field1, Field2 = o.Field2 }"
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Class, Class>>(xInit, parameter);

        var compiled = lambda.Compile();

        var res = myList.Select(compiled).ToList();
```

But, in "res", I am getting all of the columns of type T. I just want the columns from variable "d" to be   in my result.

For eg, my type T has almost 100 columns but I just want to select 10 columns per T. and already sent all the 10 columns in "d".

Comment: What is `variable "d"`? It is only used in the snippet and not defined. Also not sure what do you mean by "I want to select 10 columns". Class in C# will have all fields which are declared for it.

Comment: @GuruStron "d" is as I said, columns, It is List<PropertyInfo>......And it is there just to get the name of the column. And Only 10 columns means just specific 10 columns (These 10 columns name are there in "d")

Comment: Is this possible to get only specific columns instead of all?

Comment: First of all there is no columns in C# class, it is either properties or fields. Then what do you mean by  "I am getting all of the columns of type T"? Are all this "columns" filled with some data? Or they are present in the resulting type but filled with default values except for the 10 you've filled?

Comment: As per my problem statement, and comments in code, it is clear that I am calling properties of the class as "columns." And then if you misunderstood this, then it is much clear by the question "Is this possible to get only specific columns instead of all?" So, I just want to return few of the properties instead of returning all (doing with new Class() will return us all the properties and also with default values)

Comment: So is this possible to do ?

Comment: As I can see - you can either generate a new class in runtime or use dynamic with `ExpandoObject`. Also question is how do you want to use the returned type.

Comment: Can you please add supposed usage of the resulting object?

Comment: @GuruStron, I want to iterate over the properties and have to use all of them to lambda expression, hence I want my properties sorted first, and I have to select different properties in each iteration......For eg, For first iteration, I have to add first 10 properties but for next iteration I have to take other properties,

Comment: How you will use after iterating? What you are planning to do with the lambda?

Comment: @GuruStron, I will create my lambda expressions and will test them by passing my class properties values...

Comment: Please update your question by showing some code.